# How to put UPDATE_CUSTOM logic hook as a global variable in Botium

Tags: payload

Is it possible to set the UPDATE_CUSTOM as a global logic hook instead of put it all over the convos.

I tried it in botium.json configuration file, but it is not working:

{"botium":{
"Capabilities":{

....

"LOGIC_HOOKS": [
{
"ref": "UPDATE_CUSTOM",
"src": "UpdateCustomLogicHook",
"global": true,
"args":[
{
"arg1":"SET_DIALOGFLOW_QUERYPARAMS",
"arg2":"payload",
"arg3":{
"key":"value"
}
}
]
}
}
}

It does not work in that way, but works if I put
UPDATE_CUSTOM SET_DIALOGFLOW_QUERYPARAMS|payload|{"key":"value"}
all over the convos.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track, but there is a small syntax error in your *botium.json* - extended the [Botium Docs](https://botium-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/05_botiumscript/index.html#update-custom) with a section how to make the *UPDATE_CUSTOM* logich hook global:

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      ...
      "LOGIC_HOOKS": [
        {
          "ref": "UPDATE_CUSTOM",
          "src": "UpdateCustomLogicHook",
          "global": true,
          "args": {
            "name": "SET_DIALOGFLOW_QUERYPARAMS",
            "arg": "payload",
            "value": { "key":"value" }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```